# I am working on SURF. But while debugging the code, it is showing an error : 'Cannot open include file'

Tags: c++

I am working on image processing using opencv and c++. In my code, I use the hedear files #include "opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp". But while debugging, an error message is showing:
error C1083: Cannot open include file:'opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp':No such file or directory.

I tried all the previous answers mentioned here. But still the error exists.

I am using visualstudio 2013 and opencv 2.4.10

How can I fix this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: That's a compiler error. The compiler can't find that header. Do you have that file?

Comment: Yes.....I found opencv_nonfree2412.lib and opencv_nonfree2412d.lib files in the opencv lib folder and added it into my project by editing the project properties (properties>>configuration>>debug>>linker>>edit additional dependencies). But still the same error occurs

Comment: There error is saying the compiler can't find the header (.hpp) file. Your solution is for the linker (.lib). Make sure the path to the "opencv2" folder in in "Properties->Configuration Properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories".

Comment: Thanks for the help.It's working now.